# Resizing window makes tabs go to next line

Tags: html, css

Here is my css and html

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url('/public/images/header.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#nav {
    background: transparent;
    height: 2.5em;
    left: -25px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1em 0 1em;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 60px 0 30px 0;
}

#nav a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 2.5em;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em #333;
}

#nav a:hover {
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em white;
    background-color: white;
    color: darkred;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em lightgray;
}

#nav a:hover.active, #nav a.active {
    background-color: white;
    background-position: 0 -60px;
    color: darkred;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em lightgray;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
 /* Spacing between tabs */;
}

#nav span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: .5em 5px 0 0;
}


<div id="header">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ol id="nav">
            <li><a id="overview" href="/overview"><span>Overview</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="analysis" href="/overview" class="active"><span>Analysis</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="dashboard" href="/dashboard"><span>My Dashboard</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="preferences" href="/overview"><span>Preferences</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="contact" href="/overview"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
            <li><a id="logout" href="/overview"><span>Sign In</span></a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

This looks fine on my screen but if I start resizing the window it makes the tabs jump around and go to the next line.  I've found that on other sites with tabs this is not the case.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These "other sites" probably have their `<div id="header">` contained in another element, such as `<div id="container">`, with an explicit width set with CSS, such as `width: 960px`:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/mBJQN/

```
<div id="container">
    YOUR HTML HERE
</div>

#container {
    width: 960px;
    position: relative
}
```

I added `position: relative` so that the `position: absolute` on `#header` will be relative to `#container` ([see here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)).

---

There is another option here, but it's probably not the one you're after.

You can add `white-space: nowrap` to `#header`, and change from `float`s to `display: inline-block`. If this *is* the option you want, let me know, because it needs a little more work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mBJQN/1/

Comment: Hey man.  Thanks for the help.  This definitely keeps the tabs from going to the next line but it keeps my header image from extending across the screen.  I've tried a couple of changes but I'm guessing since I'm specifying the size of the container I can't make the header image extend?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Edit:  Actually I'm sorry.  I wrapped the navigation in the container instead of the header.  This seemed to fix the issue.  Thanks for your help.